# passing a night in a transit airport in Schengen area the day of expiration of my visa

Tags: schengen, finland

I got my 15-day visa [from 10 Nov to 24 Nov] in Finland and I booked my ticket [from 13 to 24], but there is a little problem, when returning from Finland there is a stopover in Frankfurt-Germany that will last 12 hours so my flight back from Frankfurt to Algiers will be on Nov 25th at 9:20 am.
is that possible?

Comment: Can you clarify whether the two flights are on the same ticket, if you have any checked luggage, and where you intend to sleep during that night?

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not possible since you will be leaving the Schengen Area in Frankfurt **after** your visa has expired.

Even if the Border Control *tolerated* this, it may effect future applications since the exit stamp will show that you have overstayed.

Comment: It’s not as clear cut... OP **may** be able to go through Schengen exit passport control right after landing in Frankfurt, so still on the last day of the visa. It depends a lot on how transit is managed in Frankfurt and especially of overnight airside transit is allowed. I would suppose so in an airport the size of Frankfurt, but I’m not familiar with the details.

Comment: @jcaron This has been discussed before (somewhere). I believe the consensus was that a Boarding Card (checked at passport control) cannot be issued that early (in this case 9.5 hours before end of visa). Also the Boarding Card would be a give away of when the departure is.

Comment: @jcaron Correction: The Boarding Cards are *sometimes* checked.

Comment: The situation has been discussed many times for people departing from that final Schengen airport, I’m not so sure about a transit. Note that I’m not saying this is actually possible, but it does not seem completely impossible to me. In any case, even if possible, that’s cutting it very close, if there are any delays or cancellations it would all fall apart.

Comment: @jcaron The flight between Finnland and Germany is an internal flight. So in the sense of Immigration law, there is no transit.

Comment: Of course, it also depends on a number of other factors, asked OP for clarification of a few points.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100820/discussion-between-mark-johnson-and-jcaron).

Comment: It’s not a transit for immigration, but depending on the layout of the airport there may be a direct passage from Schengen airside to extra-Schengen airside, with a dedicated passport control, and most importantly, if OP is checked through and intends to sleep on the airport, they may already have the boarding pass. Airports usually prefer people to be waiting in the departures area, not the arrivals area, so it should be quite natural to go through passport control right away after landing.

Comment: You get your boarding passes generally _24h_ ahead of the flight, some airlines even 30 days ahead. If it's a connection, you also typically have the continuation boarding passes, no matter how many hours ahead the flight is.

Comment: @Aganju due to a murder suspect buying a ticket in another name and leaving, Boarding Passes are now sometimes checked in Frankfurt. He he shows a Boarding Pass for the day **after** his visa expires, what do you think will happen?

Comment: @Aganju  Also there are no departure flights between 23 and 05, so at some point they won't be expecting anyone at some point.

Comment: You are missing my point. I was just correcting the assumption that 'a boarding pass couldn't be issued that far ahead (9.5 hours)'. I'm not saying such a boarding pass does you any good in this situation.

Comment: I think the key issue here is ‘Is Frankfurt Airport (enter terminal number) open to next-day departing passengers overnight?’ For a 24-hour airport or maybe even one that only has a couple of hours (2–3) between the last departure of the night and the first of the morning it is much more likely to be possible than for one that closes for six hours straight.